# Issue hiding WPF FrameworkElement from the Visual Studio Toolbox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I created a WPF custom control library with some custom classes derived from FrameworkElement and I want to hide some of these classes from the Visual Studio Toolbox, but I get different issues in VS2010 and VS2013.

Here below the classes of my custom control library:

```
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public class PersonObject : FrameworkElement
{
    private string _Name = "";
    private int _Age = 0;
    private Brush _ShirtColor = Brushes.Blue;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _Age; }
        set { _Age = value; }
    }

    public Brush ShirtColor
    {
        get { return _ShirtColor; }
        set { _ShirtColor = value; }
    }
}

[ToolboxBrowsable(false), TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class ExpandablePersonObject : FrameworkElement
{
    private string _Name = "";
    private int _Age = 0;
    private Brush _ShirtColor = Brushes.Blue;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _Age; }
        set { _Age = value; }
    }

    public Brush ShirtColor
    {
        get { return _ShirtColor; }
        set { _ShirtColor = value; }
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio 2010 the issue is with the attribute DesignTimeVisible(false): when I drag the dll file into the Toolbox it shows the PersonObject class too.

In Visual Studio 2013 the issue is with the attribute ToolboxBrowsable(false): when I drag the dll file into the Toolbox the PersonObject and ExpandablePersonObject classes are not showed (and this is ok) but if I go in the properties of my custom control and I try to press the New button near the ExpandablePersonObject property I get the error: "No types are available for you to add to this collection".

What am I doing wrong? How can I make my WPF custom control library compatible with both VS2010 and VS2013?

**EDIT**:
In the meantime I found that if I derive my class from UIElement (instead of FrameworkElement) then the attribute DesignTimeVisible(false) works fine also in VS2010, but I need to derive my class from FrameworkElement to allow the data binding.

I found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/02/02/known-issue-controls-and-gac-toolbox-and-tci.aspx) that say:

---

This post covers two known issues for VS2010.

- WPF only. Public types in control assemblies installed in the GAC
  that derive from FrameworkElement or above are now required to be
  decorated with the System.ComponentModel.DesignTimeVisible(false)
  attribute in order to keep the type from appearing in the Toolbox or
  the Choose Items Dialog. Not decorating the type with this attribute,
  could result in the type being added to the Toolbox and will result
  in the type being listed in the Choose Items Dialog.
- WPF and Silverlight. Control assemblies that are installed using the
  TCI require a design-time assembly to limit the types added to the
  Toolbox and the Choose Items Dialog. Without the design-time
  assembly, all types deriving from FrameworkElement or above will be
  placed in the Toolbox and will be listed in the Choose Items Dialog.

Critical
If a control assembly is installed into the GAC and uses the TCI, you must implement both of the above steps to keep unwanted types out of the Toolbox and Choose Items.

How to Limit Types in the Toolbox and Choose Items Dialog when the Assembly is in the GAC:

In the design assembly, add the ToolboxBrowsableAttribute.No to a public control assembly type's metadata to hide it.

In the control assembly, decorate public types with the DesignTimeVisible(false)attribute to hide it.

---

I tried this approach but in this way I get the error "No types are available for you to add to this collection" in VS2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by adding the new NewItemTypesAttribute(typeof(MyFrameworkElementDerivedClass)) in the design assembly.

In this way, VS2013 shows a dropdown where the user can choose the item.